# How to post emojis with the twitter api in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, unicode

I can post tweets using the Twit library: https://github.com/ttezel/twit but i'm not being able to post emojis, i tried writing &#xe131 and decodeURIComponent('&#xe131') but it doesn't work, how should I write the codes for twitter to recognize them as emojis?. (semicolons were omitted here)

Comment: Use the unicode representation_e.g_. `\1F64E`. 
See [reference](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/Unicode-11.0/U110-1F600.pdf)

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Just tried, didn't worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended copying the emojis characters directly into the code  and it worked